# Collapse/Expand nested div in Angular 6

Tags: html, angular, angular6, ngfor

I am developing a schedule like structure using div. And my design looks like this.[image]

What i want is when loading, only 1st level should be displayed (all venues) and when clicking on venue its immediate child should be displayed and so on. Is there any way to do so. my html is:

```
<div class="div-table">
    <div class="div-table-row">
        <div class="div-header-col" style="visibility: hidden;">A</div>
        <div *ngFor="let date of dates" class="div-date-col">{{date | date:'d E'}}</div>
    </div>


    <!-- level1 -->
    <div *ngFor="let venue of venues" class="level1" style="color: red">
        <div class="div-table-row-level1" >
            <div class="div-header-col">{{venue.name}}</div>
            <div *ngFor="let x of dates" class="div-event-level1-col"></div>
        </div>

        <!-- level2 -->
        <div *ngFor="let category of venue.categories" class="level2" style="color: blue">
            <div class="div-table-row-level2">
                <div class="div-header-col" style="padding-left: 10px">{{category.name}}</div>
                <div *ngFor="let x of dates" class="div-event-level2-col"></div>
            </div>

            <!-- level3 -->
            <div *ngFor="let asset of category.assets" class="level3" style="color: green">
                <div class="div-table-row-level3">
                    <div class="div-header-col" style="padding-left: 20px">{{asset.name}}</div>
                    <div *ngFor="let x of dates" class="div-event-level3-col assest-hover" "></div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My data for the table(div) is :

```
[  
   {  
      "id":1,
      "name":"venue1",
      "categories":[  
         {  
            "id":1,
            "name":"cat1",
            "assets":[  
               {  
                  "id":1,
                  "name":"assest1"
               },
               {  
                  "id":2,
                  "name":"assest2"
               }
            ]
         },
         {  
            "id":2,
            "name":"cat2",
            "assets":[  
               {  
                  "id":3,
                  "name":"assest3"
               },
               {  
                  "id":4,
                  "name":"assest4"
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   },
   {  
      "id":2,
      "name":"venue2",
      "categories":[  
         {  
            "id":3,
            "name":"cat3",
            "assets":[  
               {  
                  "id":5,
                  "name":"assest5"
               },
               {  
                  "id":6,
                  "name":"assest6"
               }
            ]
         },
         {  
            "id":4,
            "name":"cat4",
            "assets":[  
               {  
                  "id":7,
                  "name":"assest7"
               },
               {  
                  "id":8,
                  "name":"assest8"
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   },{  
      "id":3,
      "name":"venue3",
      "categories":[  
         {  
            "id":5,
            "name":"cat5",
            "assets":[  
               {  
                  "id":9,
                  "name":"assest9"
               },
               {  
                  "id":10,
                  "name":"assest10"
               }
            ]
         },
         {  
            "id":6,
            "name":"cat6",
            "assets":[  
               {  
                  "id":11,
                  "name":"assest11"
               },
               {  
                  "id":12,
                  "name":"assest12"
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

Comment: Html template is looking fine. What is challenge  here ?

Comment: @SunilSingh hiding and showing the element as per the click...

Comment: @SunilSingh On first load, only LEVEL 1 should be displayed and when clicked on any of the LEVEL 1 its child LVEL 2 should be displayed. And so on. That's the challenge here.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you have entire data loaded together then you have good news that it can be implemented in a very simple way -

You can play around `Element Reference`. Nothing needs to be managed from `ts` file.

### in html

```
   <div *ngFor="let venue of venues" class="level1" style="color: red" 
      (click)="ele.class = ele.class == 'showChildren' ? '' :  'showChildren'"
  [ngClass]="{ hideChildren : ele.class !== 'showChildren' }">
```

Repeat the same for all `parent` `div`

### in CSS

```
.hideChildren>div{
   display: none;
}
```

Here is the working copy- https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-n43ihd

There are some more way to handle if the data is being fetched in Asynchronous fashion. Then these logic will move to `ts` file.

Comment: Thanks. This work fine for expanding. But will it be working with COLLAPSE function. I will work around a solution to fix that.

Comment: Updated the answer with collapse option. Note : css change is also changed to handle closest children.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed answer, I am trying to make it work with everything expanded at first but cannot seem to be able to, could you help me with that?

Comment: I finally got it working like this
`(click)="ele.class = (ele.class == 'showChildren') ? 'hideChildren' :  'showChildren'"
 [ngClass]="{ hideChildren : ele.class == 'showChildren',  showChildren : ele.class == 'hideChildren'}"`. Thnx anyway!

Answer (score -3):

You can try to hide component's on-load, and set them to visible onClick

```
$scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function() {
    // Hide all unwanted div's here
});
```

Comment: That  i had tried using css. But the challenge is how to display the correct child of the clicked parent.